# How to get forever cli to run over io.js

Tags: node.js, forever, io.js

I've just installed io.js, I am trying to use forever to restart my server on file change, but it's still running on node.js, how do I move it over to io.js?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-c` flag.

```
-c  COMMAND      COMMAND to execute (defaults to node)
```

Comment: `forever start -c 'iojs' index.js`

Answer (score 0):

oops! just found a quick hack,
I opened `/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever` (where forever was installed globally) and changed the shebang to open iojs instead of node.

Comment: modifying contents of any node module directly is really bad practice. If you really need to modify a module you should fork the project in github, make the change you need, push the modified branch to your own repo, and `npm install -g git://github.com/myusername/foreverjs.git` it from there.  
However in the case of this question, there's no need to modify the source. the `-c` command argument is perfect for what you need.